# JDBC PreparedStatement results in MySQL syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting the error **"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''orderr'' at line 1"**  - so I assume the error is that I have used two **'** but in my code I have not used any **'**. NB the table is actually named orderr.

```
public void insertIntoDatabase(String table, Object... entries) {       // take a table and 
    Connection con = connect();                                         //add entries
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    StringBuffer columnNames = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer sbEntries = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        if (entries[i] instanceof Integer)
            sbEntries.append((Integer) entries[i]); 
        else if (entries[i] instanceof String)      
            sbEntries.append((String) entries[i]); 

        if (i != entries.length - 1)//if not last entry add 
            sbEntries.append(" ,"); // a ' ,'.
    }
    try {
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("select * from ? ;");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, table);
        preparedStatement2 = con
                .prepareStatement("Insert into ?( ? ) values ( ? );");
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); // get the
                                                                // number of
                                                                // columns
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd; // for the table
        rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) { // get column names, add to 
            columnNames.append(rsmd.getColumnName(i)); // to sb
            if (i != columnCount)
                columnNames.append(" ,");
        }
        columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        preparedStatement2.setString(1, table);                     
        preparedStatement2.setString(2, columnNames.toString());    //add sb's to statement
        preparedStatement2.setString(3, sbEntries.toString());
        preparedStatement2.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("2" + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            if(preparedStatement2 != null){
                preparedStatement2.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print("3" +e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see the syntax? If you are trying to `orderr` by then change it to `order by` with one r :)

Comment: In the first prepared statement I am selecting all from the the table named 'orderr' (mySQL has a keyword named 'order') in the second statement I inserting into the table called 'orderr'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most databases you can't parametrize object names like table names, in MySQL you theoretically can as MySQL Connector/J by default doesn't use server side parameters, but instead it rewrites the query before sending it to the server. However the value will be inserted as a quoted string, and object names cannot be a quoted string, so it still won't work.

So `INSERT INTO ?` or `SELECT ... FROM ?` will not work, as it produces `INSERT INTO 'theTable'` or `SELECT ... FROM 'theTable'`.

The object names need to be part of the actual query. Do not use parameters for them. Most other databases (or their drivers) would have thrown an exception for having a parameter in this position.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. You cannot set table name in SQL statements using prepared statement.
2. You have `;` in the SQL statement.

Once you take care of above points, your code should work.

Comment: thanks this solved two big questions for me! Postgres is really anal about semicolons so I formatted those into my queries along with the column names